# rosdep doesn't "see" Python 3 package

Tags: ros, rosdep, python3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i'm installing cartography,when i executing the command

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro=${ROS_DISTRO} -y
```

in https://google-cartographer-ros.readthedocs.io/en/latest/compilation.html,it always turn to executing command

```
sudo -H apt-get install -y python-sphinx
```

however,i'm using python3 and the rosdep version in my ubuntu20.04LTS is python3-rosdep,why it will turn to install python-sphinx?i think the right sphinx version for this is python3-sphinx and i apt-get install it and it does be installed ,then it still reports the same error.therefore i am stuck in the above commands.

here are the errors:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python-sphinx is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  sphinx-doc sphinx-common

E: Package 'python-sphinx' has no installation candidate
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
  apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install -y python-sphinx] failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/363609/rosdep-doesn%27t-%22see%22-python-3-package/) by [jacki](https://answers.ros.org/users/57083/jacki/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2020-10-16

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosdep will attempt to install whatever dependency is declared in the package.xml files for the packages that you are asking it to resolve.

In this case I believe that you're using a package that declares an explicit dependency on the rosdep key [`python-sphinx`](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/e285a71da2a34753855b1cc59827cc5bb30b59c6/rosdep/python.yaml#L4470-L4487)

You are either using the wrong branch for that package or it has not yet been updated to support a python3 version of the rosdep, [`python3-sphinx`](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/e285a71da2a34753855b1cc59827cc5bb30b59c6/rosdep/python.yaml#L6651)

If the package has not been updated yet a pull request to help the packages at issue migrate to be Python 3 compatible would I'm sure be appreciated. There's a guide here: http://wiki.ros.org/UsingPython3

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2020-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jacki](https://answers.ros.org/users/57083/jacki/) on 2020-10-21**:
thanks for answering，i just install python3-sphinx by apt and ignore “rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro=${ROS_DISTRO} -y”，then i solve dependencies once i encountered while compling cartographer.